# Prestashop keep cart after payment error

Tags: prestashop, cart

I would like to keep every products in my cart even if there is a payment error, I found that when the order is inserted in the database, the current cart session is "deleted" and a new one is created.

Is there a way to keep my cart session ? Or where is this happening ?

Answer (score -1):

Finally found a way after 3 days :
In FrontController

```
if ($cart->OrderExists())
{
    unset($this->context->cookie->id_cart, $cart, $this->context->cookie->checkedTOS);
    $this->context->cookie->check_cgv = false;
}
```

This sample of code is deleting the cart session, I just need to remove this

```
$this->context->cookie->id_cart, $cart
```

Comment: you asked question an hour ago, how you "found a way after 3 days"?)

Comment: I asked here after 3 days of searching by my own.